# Wedge product of differential and volume form

Tags: analysis, differential-forms

Let $f(x)$ be a $C^1$ function defined on $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $\nabla f(x) \neq 0$ for any $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$. If $d\sigma$ is the volume form on hypersurface $f(x)=c$ induced from $\mathbb{R}^n$ then how to show the equality
$$
    df \wedge d\sigma = |\nabla f| \, dx^1 \wedge \ldots \wedge dx^n?
$$
The main problem is that I don't know to what equal $d\sigma(X_p^1,\ldots,X_p^{n-1})$ for tangent vectors $X_p^1,\ldots,X_p^{n-1} \in T_p \mathbb{R}^n$. Any hint is welcome.

Comment: What's your definition of "volume form"?

Comment: @JesseMadnick nowhere vanishing form of maximal degree (i.e. n-1) such that its value on $(n-1)$-uple of tangent vectors $X_p^1,\ldots,X_p^{n-1}$ to $S$ (hypersurface) in point $p \in S$ is the volume (signed) of parallelepiped generated by them (right?)

Comment: @JesseMadnick The OP seems to make that explicit as his problem.

Comment: Are you working with Euclidean or affine geometry? Do you have an idea of a normal vector, e.g. a unit normal or a Blaschke normal?

Comment: @FlybyNight I'm working with Euclidean geometry and I have an idea of normal space as an orthogonal complement to tangent space. So here it is spanned by $\nabla f(x)$, if I'm not mistaken. So unit normal is just $\frac{\nabla f}{|\nabla f|}$

Comment: Maybe $d\sigma$ is really an $(n-1)$-dimensional form on the WHOLE $\mathbb{R}^n$ that gives volume (signed) of parallelepipeds spanned by $(n-1)$ tangent vectors to an arbitrary point $p \in \mathbb{R}^n$?

Comment: I have seen that in affine geometry. We can define a volume form on a surface by saying that the volume of two tangent vectors to a surface is the volume of those two vectors *and* the normal in three-space. But there's also another definition of volume form which depends on the Riemannian metric and hold for abstract, non-embedded manifolds: $\omega = \sqrt{|g|}\operatorname{d}\!x^1\wedge\ldots\wedge \operatorname{d}\!x^{n-1}$.

Comment: @FlybyNight Do this definitions coincide for embedded manifolds if we use Euclidean metric $g$ induced from $\mathbb{R}^n$? By the way, integration with respect to $d\sigma$ specified in my post is equivalent to integration with respect to $(n-1)$-dimensional Hausdorff measure for smooth functions with compact support on $S$. Maybe this can help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider the case of an orientable surface in three-space. The surface has a unit normal ${\bf n} = (n^1,n^2,n^3).$ The volume form of our surface is given by:

$$\operatorname{d}\!\omega = n^1 \operatorname{d}\!y \wedge \operatorname{d}\!z + n^2\operatorname{d}\!z\wedge \operatorname{d}\!x + n^3\operatorname{d}\!x\wedge\operatorname{d}\!y$$

In the case where $M = \{f(x,y,z)=0\}$ the, as you have said,

$${\bf n} = \frac{(f_x,f_y,f_z)}{\sqrt{f_x^2+f_y^2+f_z^2}}$$

It follows that:

$$\operatorname{d}\!\omega = \frac{f_x \operatorname{d}\!y \wedge \operatorname{d}\!z + f_y\operatorname{d}\!z\wedge \operatorname{d}\!x + f_z\operatorname{d}\!x\wedge\operatorname{d}\!y}{\sqrt{f_x^2+f_y^2+f_z^2}}$$

As you already know: $\operatorname{d}\!f = f_z\operatorname{d}\!x + f_y\operatorname{d}\!y +f_z\operatorname{d}\!z$. Hence

\begin{array}{ccc}
\operatorname{d}\!f \wedge \operatorname{d}\!\omega &=& \frac{f_x^2+f_y^2+f_z^2}{\sqrt{f_x^2+f_y^2+f_z^2}}\operatorname{d}\!x\wedge\operatorname{d}\!y\wedge\operatorname{d}\!z \\
\\
&=& |\nabla f| \, \operatorname{d}\!x\wedge\operatorname{d}\!y\wedge\operatorname{d}\!z
\end{array}

Comment: Hence in $n$ dimensions $d\omega = \frac{\partial f}{\partial x^k} \frac{1}{|\nabla f(x)|} (\ast dx^k)$ (where Hodge star $\ast$ corresponds to Euclidean metric), right?

Comment: I think you're missing a summation. As far as I remember $\star (\operatorname{d}\!x) = \operatorname{d}\!y\wedge\operatorname{d}\!z$, $\star (\operatorname{d}\!y) = \operatorname{d}\!z\wedge\operatorname{d}\!x$ and $\star(\operatorname{d}\!z) = \operatorname{d}\!x  \wedge\operatorname{d}\!y$. Hence, in $n$-dimensions,

$$\operatorname{d}\!\omega = \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{{\partial f}/{\partial x^k}}{|\nabla f|} \ \left[\star(\operatorname{d}\!x^k)\right]$$

Comment: Great thanks! As I see you use definition of volume form via normal vector. And If we use one via Euclidean metric will we obtain the same form?

Comment: Yes, they coincide (I've found $vol_g$).